# Hibernate Restrictions - how can I query with multiple values?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

I am new to Hibernate Restrictions and need some help:

I am having a scenario that I need to find all the records where "identifier" is "HB001" or "HB002", "HB003" &"HB004". That is to say, it should return 4 rows, each row has "identifier" as "HB00*".

```
//here is the code
Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(ENTITY_CLASS); 

List<String> ids = getIds(); //ids contains "HB001", "HB002", "HB003", "HB004" and I am sure this step has no issue. 
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("identifier", ids));
...
```

looks like the `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("identifier", ids))` is not correct and the query returns null.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `criteria.add(Restrictions.in("identifier", ids));` and your `ids` should be a collection like an `ArrayList`.

Just noticed that your `ids` is already a List, you can directly use `Restrictions.in`.